# Eigen Sparse Vector : Find max coefficient

Tags: c++, max, sparse-matrix, eigen

I am working with sparse vector with Eigen, and I need to find an efficient way to compute the index of the max coefficient (or the nth max coefficient).

My initial method uses Eigen::SparseVector::InnerIterator, however it does not compute the right value in the case of vector containing only zeros and negative value because InnerIterator only iterate on non-zero values.

How to implement it in order to take into account zero values ?

Comment: So if all your entries are negative, you would like the index of the first empty element?

Comment: BTW, what's the average number of non zeros versus the vector size? If the ratio is above, say, 20%, then I'd recommend switching to a dense storage with explicit zeros. You'll get both more performance and simplicity.

Comment: Yes, ggael, that is the idea. But I do not know what is the most efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

To get the index of the largest non-zero element, you can use this function:

```
Eigen::Index maxRow(Eigen::SparseVector<double> const & v)
{
    Eigen::Index nnz = v.nonZeros();
    Eigen::Index rowIdx;
    double value = Eigen::VectorXd::Map(v.valuePtr(), nnz).maxCoeff(&rowIdx);
    // requires special handling if value <= 0.0
    return v.innerIndexPtr()[rowIdx];
}
```

In case `value <=0` (and `v.nonZeros()<v.size()`), you can iterate through `innerIndexPtr()` until you find a gap between consecutive elements (or write something more sophisticated using `std::lower_bound`)

For getting the nth largest element it depends on how large your `n` is relative to the vector size, how many non-zeros you have, if you can modify your `SparseVector`, etc.

Especially, if `n` is relatively large, consider to [partition](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partition_copy/) your elements into positive and negative elements, then using [`std::nth_element`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/nth_element/) in the correct half.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the index array (`innerIndices` I think) as well at the same time as the inner iterator.